# EmberJS - record with hasMany relation fails to load

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage, ember-data

I am using EmberJS 1.0.0 with Ember Data 1.0.0 beta and the latest version of the [LocalStorage Adapter](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter). When I try to load a record with a hasMany relationship from the store I get the follwing error:

ember-1.0.0.js (Line 394)

> Assertion failed: You looked up the 'items' relationship on
>   'App.List:ember236:1' but some of the associated records were not
>   loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent
>   record, or specify that the relationship is async (DS.attr({ async:
>   true }))

and ember-data.js (Line 2530)

> TypeError: resolver is undefined
>   }).then(resolver.resolve, resolver.reject);

Quick demo app: http://jsbin.com/oKuPev/49 (watch the console)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">      
    List: {{name}}       
    <div>    
        {{#each items}}
            {{id}} - {{name}}<br/>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.App = Ember.Application.create({});        
    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({});

    var FIXTURES = {
      'App.List': {
        records: {
          '1': { id: '1', name: 'The List', items: ['1','2'] }
        }
      },
      'App.Item': {
        records: {
          '1': { id: '1', name: 'item 1', list: '1' },
          '2': { id: '2', name: 'item 2', list: '1' }
        }
      }
    }

    // Store fixtures in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('DS.LSAdapter', JSON.stringify(FIXTURES));

    // Models
    App.List = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        items: DS.hasMany('item')
    });  

    App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string') ,
        list: DS.belongsTo('list')
    });


    // Route  
    App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({    
        model: function() {
          // Fails!!!
          return this.store.find('list', 1);           
        }
    });       

  </script>
```

I'm not sure if the problem is ember.js, ember-data.js or the LocalStorage adapter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to define "items" on your model as being async in nature as ember makes separate requests for those models and then joins them together asynchronously.

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  items: DS.hasMany('item',{async:true})
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that before, but for some reason it didn't work either. Now it worked but I am using Ember Model now anyway.

Comment: Where can I read more about the async parameter? I cannot find it in the ember data docs?

Comment: Came here looking for more explanation of `async` parameter. Can't find anything regarding what this actually does.

Comment: Anyone looking for more info, see [this discussion](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-an-async-relationship-async-true-vs-async-false/4107/8)

Answer (score 3):

This works if you define `items` as an asynchronous relationship.

`item: DS.hasMany('item',{async:true})`

Here's a working jsbin : http://jsbin.com/oKuPev/53/edit

Comment: Is this the correct link for the JSBin? Doesn't appear to be showing the correct code. Kindly confirm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else that stumbles on this thread b/c associations aren't loading (but w/o an error) notice the `items: [1, 2]` which associates the parent to child records.